# GWT Comet Integration (Server Push) Help

Tags: gwt, comet, server-push, reverse-ajax

I am getting some difficulties with comet on the server

First, I am working with the default configuration of the gwt hosted
mode(i.e. using jetty), do i need to make any change to enable comet

Now, on the server what I want is a client will send a request and
then he will be enrolled in a so-called group. Whenever, any change
happens to all group, all client connected to that group are made
aware.

Can someone help with this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/wiki/GettingStarted